# Logging on to SQL Server from a Windows 8.1 PC over a VPN

Tags: windows-8, vpn, domain, sql-server

I currently work remotely (new position) and am logged into my Windows 8.1 development machine with my Windows Live account. I can connect to our corporate LAN via VPN but can not access SQL Server using an `Integrated Security=SSPI` connection string.

Logging on to SQL Management Studio gives me the below error as I'm not on that domain.

[image]

Is there a method of logging onto SQL Server through either SQL Management Studio or using an appropriate connection string in my application? Is the simplest solution to just set up a user name and password on the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Microsoft makes the default windows 8 account part of the Microsoft.com domain. When SQL server gets your login request of is coming from an untrusted domain and rejects the connection.

You can do one of three things. Have your network admin add the Microsoft domain as a trusted domain. This has a few security implications.

Alternatively, next time you're in the office log onto the laptop using a domain account in the same domain as the SQL server.

And of course you could use a different security method than integrated. That's ultimately what I do for development purposes.